# API isn't getting called on button click

Tags: node.js, csv, vue.js

I have an API that exports the User table into CSV format. When I hit this route/API directly it works perfectly, it generates a file and saves it on the computer. Now I want that process to happen on button click. When an export button is clicked it should call a function and in that function I call this API, but it does nothing on click.

Here is my API route:

```
app.get('/exporttocsv', function (req, res, next) {
    var date = dateTime({ local: false }).toString()
    var upddate = date.split(' ').join('-')
    var filename = "HotelApp_User" + upddate + ".csv"
    User.find({}).select('-__v').lean().exec({}, function (err, products) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
        res.csv(products, true);
    });
});

// Here is my button and click code
<div><button class="btn btn-dark" style="float:right;margin-top:20px" v-on:click="exportU()">Export</button></div>

exportU(){
    this.axios.get('http://localhost:3000/Customer/exporttocsv')
}
```

Comment: is it making a request at all? have you checked network tab? Is there any error??

Comment: I would guess the route actually *is* getting called, but your current click code does absolutely nothing whatsoever with the response, discarding it and outputting no information that would let you know it worked

Comment: yes i have checked this route by hitting it directly in browser , it works .. but at click dont :( .. can you write me a proper code means how to call this route on click and what to do with response .. thanks

Comment: @rizwanraza 1. Do you see any error messages in the console? 2. Can you see the request being attempted in the Network tab of the developer tools after you click the button? 3. Have you tried putting console logging in the `exportU` method to confirm that it is being called at all?

Comment: So, `app.get('/exporttocsv', ...)` does not look like it would line up with `http://localhost:3000/Customer/exporttocsv` unless you have a proxy or a sub-app in Express that strips off the `/Customer` part of the URL.  Do you?

Comment: Also, whenever something isn't working, you should hook up all possible error handlers and log everything.  `axios.get(...).catch(err => console.log(err))`.